# creating new variable based on other variables from different columns in df

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe

I am trying to create a new variable (incomeX) in a data frame
based on the last character of the colnames so if:

```
      income1 income2 income3 income4 income5
1        0       1       0       0       0
2        1       0       0       0       0
3        1       0       0       0       0
4        1       0       0       0       0
5        1       0       0       0       0
6        1       0       0       0       0
7        0       1       0       0       0
8        1       0       0       0       0
9        1       0       0       0       0
10       0       0       0       1       0
```

I would get:

```
     income1 income2 income3 income4 income5 incomeX
1        0       1       0       0       0      2
2        1       0       0       0       0      1
3        1       0       0       0       0      1
4        1       0       0       0       0      1
5        1       0       0       0       0      1
6        1       0       0       0       0      1
7        0       1       0       0       0      2
8        1       0       0       0       0      1
9        1       0       0       0       0      1
10       0       0       0       1       0      4
```

Comment: Data frames show up in several languages (R and Python with Pandas for instance) so please specify a language tag

Comment: Sorry I am trying to learn R

Comment: income1 income2 income3 income4 income5
0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0

Comment: i don't want to just do this, because I may need to do it for several other columns.

Comment: income$incomeX <- ifelse(income$income1 == 1, income$incomeX <- 1,
ifelse(income$income2 == 1, income$incomeX <- 2, 
ifelse(income$income3 == 1, income$incomeX <- 3, 
ifelse(income$income4 == 1, income$incomeX <- 4,
ifelse(income$income5 == 1, income$incomeX <- 5, NA)))))

Comment: This question ought to have been solved with `which`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach using the `tidyverse`.  We convert the data to a tidy data form, separate the characters `income` from numbers, select rows where the value == 1, and then use the `rowId` to merge the results back into the original data.

```
inputData <- " rowId     income1 income2 income3 income4 income5
1        0       1       0       0       0
2        1       0       0       0       0
3        1       0       0       0       0
4        1       0       0       0       0
5        1       0       0       0       0
6        1       0       0       0       0
7        0       1       0       0       0
8        1       0       0       0       0
9        1       0       0       0       0
10       0       0       0       1       0
"
data <- read.table(text=inputData,header=TRUE)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% gather(variable,value,-rowId) %>%
     extract(variable,into = c("varname", "number"), 
             regex = "([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)") %>%
     filter(value == 1) %>% rename(incomeX = number) %>%
     select(-value,-varname) %>%
     left_join(data,.) %>% arrange(rowId)
```

...and the output:

```
+      left_join(data,.) %>% arrange(rowId)
Joining, by = "rowId"
   rowId income1 income2 income3 income4 income5 incomeX
1      1       0       1       0       0       0       2
2      2       1       0       0       0       0       1
3      3       1       0       0       0       0       1
4      4       1       0       0       0       0       1
5      5       1       0       0       0       0       1
6      6       1       0       0       0       0       1
7      7       0       1       0       0       0       2
8      8       1       0       0       0       0       1
9      9       1       0       0       0       0       1
10    10       0       0       0       1       0       4
>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `which` from base r to solve this:

```
s=which(data==1,arr.ind = T)
data$IncomeX[s[,1]]=s[,2]
data
   income1 income2 income3 income4 income5 IncomeX
1        0       1       0       0       0       2
2        1       0       0       0       0       1
3        1       0       0       0       0       1
4        1       0       0       0       0       1
5        1       0       0       0       0       1
6        1       0       0       0       0       1
7        0       1       0       0       0       2
8        1       0       0       0       0       1
9        1       0       0       0       0       1
10       0       0       0       1       0       4
```